# How to not select last and bottom divs in a row when applying a margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have setup a row of divs and I would like to remove the margin that I have used to space out each of them on the last div in the row and the bottom margin.

```css
#feature-box-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.feature-box {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 12px;
  color: grey;
  border: 1px solid #4F5B93;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.feature-box img {
  height: 48px;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.feature-box p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="feature-box-container">

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/router-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/template-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/security-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/ssl-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis.</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/data-access-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/notification-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

</div>
```

I have set a margin-right and margin-bottom of 50px but I don't want that applied to the last div in the row and the bottom ones.

Probably best to expand the snippet to see rows of divs.

Is this possible using CSS and still being able to add new divs?

Comment: Do you know about the :last-child pseudo selector ? `parent child:last-child{margin-bottom:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

You probably look for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

> The :last-child CSS pseudo-class represents the last element among a group of sibling elements.

```css
#feature-box-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.feature-box {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 12px;
  color: grey;
  border: 1px solid #4F5B93;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.feature-box:last-child {
  margin-bottom: auto;/* or 0 */
}

.feature-box img {
  height: 48px;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.feature-box p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="feature-box-container">

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/router-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/template-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/security-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/ssl-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis.</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/data-access-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/notification-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is many way to removing margin from last child.
you can also use :last-child pseudo selector to remove margin from last child.or
you can also use [:not selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) for removing margin from last child. like this way.

```
<div id="feature-box-container">

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/router-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/template-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/security-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/ssl-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis.</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/data-access-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

  <div class="feature-box">

    <img src="images/notification-icon.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nisi mollis lacus sagittis</p>

  </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
#feature-box-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.feature-box {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 12px;
  color: grey;
  border: 1px solid #4F5B93;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.feature-box:not(:last-child){
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.feature-box img {
  height: 48px;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.feature-box p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

or you can also use [:nth-last-of-type() Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-last-of-type.asp) for removing last child margin.
you can choose any of them to remove last child margin.

thank you